# excel vlookup to match on 2 criterias and return a 3rd result

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Sheet is on the cloud, and being used by people with Google Sheets, so VBA is out unfortunately.

Trying to get a vlookup to check 'Monday!A3' with 'Weekly Roster!E:E', but it also has to match 'Monday!E1' with 'Weekly Roster!G:G' and then returned 'Weekly Roster!H'

If this was VBA I'd be able to smash it out, but unfortunately its not!

Have tried numerous different ways, and they don't work! Here are some below examples;

```
=AND(VLOOKUP(E1,'Weekly Roster'!A:M,8,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A3,'Weekly Roster'!A:M,8,FALSE))
=VLOOKUP(A3, IF(E1='Weekly Roster'!G:G,'Weekly Roster'!H:H,""), 8, FALSE)
```

(And some others that have been deleted!)

If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be fantastic! Appreciate the help!

Sheet = Monday -> Matching 'Monday!A3' to 'Weekly Roster!E:E' and then also matching 'Monday!E1' to 'Weekly Roster!G:G' and returning 'Weekly Roster!H'

Monday Sheet:
[image: Monday Sheet]

Weekly Roster:
[image: Weekly Roster]

Comment: if we can see a sample of your data for everyone can help you i guess

Comment: Pictures attached! First one, is Monday, where I'm matching A3 (And onwards) to 'Weekly Roster!E:E' and also matching 'Monday!E1' to 'Weekly Roster!G:G' and returning 'Weekly Roster:H'

Comment: is your Badge # is the same reference with Emp #?

Comment: Certainly is!!!

Comment: how about SING5580 is duplicated in this scenario which data do you want?

Comment: Ah, it depends on the second vlookup as it displays it for the entire week.

Comment: it will depend on your cell A3, A4 so on, ok try to see of what I have tried and attached an image as will,

Comment: your line says it all: Trying to get a vlookup to check 'Monday!A3' with 'Weekly Roster!E:E', but it also has to match 'Monday!E1' with 'Weekly Roster!G:G' and then returned 'Weekly Roster!H'  ...now just write   =filter(Weekly Roster!H:H,Weekly Roster!E:E=Monday!$A3, Weekly Roster!G:G=Monday!$E$1)   ... i think that's it

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

Try this:

1. Add a new column in "Monday" Sheet at the beginning ("A" column and name it index) , Badge column will be on "B" now
2. In Cell A3 use: B3&"-"&$E$1 and fill it down for the rest of rows
3. Add a new column in "Weekly Roster" Sheet at the beginning ("A" column and name it index)
4. as the columns will be shifted now in Cell A2 use: F2&"-"&H2 and fill it down for the rest of rows
5. the Vlookup will be :

> VLOOKUP(A3,'Weekly Roster'!A:N,9,FALSE)

Comment: Cheers! The Weekly Report is just an export out of our rostering program, no other way around it is there by chance?

Comment: Worked like a dream appreciate it! Never thought about creating a new string to match only the one!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Filter]

try like this in cell D2 in your Monday Sheet

```
=FILTER(FILTER('Weekly Roster'!E1:H3,('Weekly Roster'!G1:G3=$E$1)*('Weekly Roster'!E1:E3=A4)),{0,0,0,1})
```